# Trying to retrieve Region(State) and City and Campaign Metrics from Google Ads campaigns

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-ads-api

Im trying to make a GAQL to retrieve some data like Clicks, Impressions from my campaigns separated by City and State (Like NY or FL or CA)
I'm using Python and google-ads = "^21.3.0" to access the google ads data.
Im also authenticated with an MCC account.
This is my Query:

`query = f""" SELECT campaign.name, metrics.impressions, metrics.clicks, metrics.cost_micros, campaign.id, segments.date, customer.id, campaign.campaign_group, customer.descriptive_name, campaign_criterion.proximity.address.city_name, campaign_criterion.proximity.address.country_code, campaign_criterion.proximity.address.postal_code, campaign_criterion.proximity.address.province_name FROM location_view WHERE segments.date = '{date}' AND campaign_criterion.type = 'PROXIMITY' """`
The problem here is: The campaign_criterion.proximity fields like city_name, country_code, postal_code, etc,  just dont appear in my result, its just like i didnt put them it in my select.  Is there something wrong with my query or maybe is there possible that my MCC account doesnt have all permissions that is needed to get this information ?

I need a result like this:
`[ { "campaign": "campaign_1", "clicks": 10, "impressions": 5, "city": "São Paulo", "state": "São Paulo" }, { "campaign": "campaign_1", "clicks": 8, "impressions": 2, "city": "Goiania", "state": "Goiás" } ]`